ethers hashMessage and solidity keccak256
Hi guys i try to hash message in my app like this
 const hash = ethers.hashMessage(msg+'-'+salt)

then verify hash in smart contract like this
bytes32   c  = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg,"-",salt ));
if(hash==c){
    return true;
}

but my verification always fail,i am guess i am do something wrong

As in Solidity, keccak256 hashing is used. So, you need to use the same while hashing the message in your app (off-chain).
So, in your app, replace this line:
const hash = ethers.hashMessage(msg+'-'+salt)

with:
const hash = ethers.keccak256(ethers.toUtf8Bytes(msg + '-' + salt))

Now, it'll generate the same hash as generated by:
keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg,"-",salt)) in solidity.
